# Will this sitemap get me de indexed from Google?

Tags: google, search-engines, sitemap, search-engine-indexing

My site's URL (web address) is:  http://quantlabs.net/private/sitemap.xml
Description (including timeline of any changes made):

Will this sitemap get me de-indexed from Google?

My new site map just got spidered by Google for some reason. It is located at http://quantlabs.net/private/sitemap.xml, is this in danger of getting me de-indexed from Google's index. Does it look like spam even though it is not meant to be?

I am trying to figure the limitation in terms of Google's threshold before they deem it a spammy sitemap. This is sitemap contains automated postings which are different with the stock symbol provided. The amount of postings within the Sitemap are quite a few in a small amount of time.

Comment: What are you specifically worried about?  I looked at the sitemap and it is pretty small and the links don't look malicious.

Answer (score 2):

Why would this get you de-indexed? It's just an XML sitemap. To be "de-listed" by Google or any other search engine you would have to violate their terms of service. You're not only not doing that but you're doing something they are *encouraging* you to do: submitting an XML sitemap so they can find your content. If you're unsure how an XML sitemap should look just go to the [official XML sitemap website](http://sitemaps.org/) and read up on what is acceptable and what isn't.

Answer (score 2):

I checked out your sitemap and I noticed all of your links go to pages that require a log in.  With that in mind Google won't mark your site as spam but they will never be able to index anything except your log in page which won't get you ranked for anything.

If it concerns you or you don't want your sitemap indexed then add a robot.txt file to your directory and set it to:

```
User-agent: *
disallow: /
```

If you want to learn all about what Google expects and requires for a good site and to not be marked as spam, checkout, http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769.  It is a page from Google with all of their Webmaster Guidelines.  It isn't a huge amount of reading and it is really worth reading.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks so much! I posted this so many places on snobby forums including Google, this was the most helpful. This was very valuable for me!